# Can't install SQL Server Driver (PHP / Heroku)

Tags: php, sql-server, heroku

Can't install ext-sqlsrv & ext-pdo_sqlsrv php extensions on Heroku Platform.

I'm following the repo: https://github.com/heroku-softtrends/heroku-php-sqlsrv-buildpack

.user.ini

```
extension = sqlsrv.so
extension = pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Aptfile

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/libodbc1_2.3.7_amd64.deb
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/odbcinst_2.3.7_amd64.deb
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/odbcinst1debian2_2.3.7_amd64.deb
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/unixodbc_2.3.7_amd64.deb
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/unixodbc-dev_2.3.7_amd64.deb
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.6.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

`HEROKU_PHP_PLATFORM_REPOSITORIES`: https://github.com/heroku-softtrends/mssql-server-drivers-for-php/raw/main/5.9.0/ubuntu/20.04/php/8.0/nts/packages.json

However, when I attempt to push to Heroku I get the following error:

```
remote:          Problem 1
remote:            - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-sqlsrv ^5.9 but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sqlsrv extension.
remote:          Problem 2
remote:            - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-pdo_sqlsrv ^5.9 but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pdo_sqlsrv extension.
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `Aptfile` and the `HEROKU_PHP_PLATFORM_REPOSITORIES` environment variable?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated my description with Aptfile and HEROKU_PHP_PLATFORM_REPOSITORIES values.